# Importing orders from .csv into Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, orders, import

I've got some orders from M1, exported into a CSV that I need to add to Magento 2. There aren't too many so I don't mind doing it manually.

I've found that adding orders through the order section of the site will only create new orders and not let me add in historical orders. Is there any way to add them to the Database or another method?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have created a module same as to import orders through csv. You can manually do by programatically order script.

Comment: Ah, would you be able to link to your module please?

Comment: I will provide you my module in zip file. I have added code for all invoice, shipment, credit memo and orders. Hope it helps you

Comment: You can download the order import module through this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i4oTreuHTcuxaKAk7smNR_KqryYozKbK/view?usp=sharing

You have to create a file on root directory importOrders.php or whatever you want to give name to a file and add code below:

Comment: Hi @Sheba, could you please share the csv file also?

Comment: @Nayem323 probably not assuming the csv is the data of real customers